# Value visible in chrome console tab but not in code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

In my php file I have a **span** under a **button** which in turn is inside a **td**

`<td class="floating-td"><button class="count"><span id="compareCounts"><?php echo $listInfo; ?></span>    </button></td>`

At the end of the file while trying to fetch the value of span through ID I'm not getting anything. But when I check in the Chrome console, I do get the values there.

```
jQuery(document).ready(($) => {
   var countVal = $('#compareCounts').text();
   // var countVal = document.getElementById("compareCounts").value;
   console.log("qwerty countVal bc-html: ", countVal);
}
```

As shown above, I tried using JS and jquery, in both the cases I'm not getting the value while running the code. Though trying `$('#compareCounts').text();` and `document.getElementById("compareCounts").value` in the console tab in Chrome does give the value.

What could be wrong here ?

Comment: Where in the document have you placed the javascript snippet?

Comment: @PhanisimhaNR after encapsulating all the html elements, inside a script tag.

Comment: Do you have multple html with `compareCounts ` id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you. I will try using jquery with on load and on button click how to get the value and console it.

```js
$(function() {
  // button click get value and console
  $(".count").click(function() {
      $('#compareCounts').text();
      console.log("btn click get value and console: ", countVal);
  });  

  // first time on load get value and console
  var countVal = $('#compareCounts').text();
  console.log("on page load get value: ", countVal);      
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Example</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <td class="floating-td">
    <button class="count">
      <span id="compareCounts">test</span>
    </button>
  </td>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple dynamic values at that time on btn click you can get the span value

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function(e){
        var a = $.trim($(this).text());
      console.log(a);
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Example</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <td class="floating-td">
    <button class="count">
      <span>test</span>
    </button>
  </td>
    <td class="floating-td">
    <button class="count">
      <span>test1</span>
    </button>
  </td>
</body>
</html>
```